# Why is this AngularJS call causing a 400 bad request error (Spring back end)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

This request below is causing a 400 bad request response:

```
$scope.addGiveaway = function(campaignId){
        var photo = $scope.photo;
        var giveaway = $scope.giveaway;
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('photo', photo);
        data.append('giveaway', giveaway);
        var uploadUrl = "/dashboard/campaigns/"+campaignId+"/giveaways";
        $http.put(uploadUrl, data, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        });
```

Here's the Spring controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addGiveaway(@RequestParam("giveaway") Giveaway giveaway, 
                                              @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo,
                                              @PathVariable("campaignId") long campaignId,
                                              Principal principal) throws Exception {
```

I have a `@RequestMapping` at the top of the entire controller class:

`@RequestMapping("/dashboard/campaigns/{campaignId}/giveaways")`

I've tried:

- Changing the `Giveaway` object to a String and using a mapper to map
  the values manually
- I've tried using `angular.toJson`
- I've ensured all of the values are being populated (no null values
  being sent from Angular).
- I've tried changing the `Content-Type` to `undefined` and to
  `multipart/form-data`

Why is this causing a 400 bad request response?

**EDIT**
Posting entire controller class as requested. It shouldn't matter though as the logger at the top of the controller is not being called. It's not getting into the code of the controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dashboard/campaigns/{campaignId}/giveaways")
public class GiveawayController {

    @Autowired
    private GiveawayService giveawayService;

    @Autowired
    private CampaignService campaignService;

    @Autowired
    private BusinessUserService businessUserService;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GiveawayController.class);

    /**
     * Uploads a giveaway to the server given data and a photo.
     * 
     * @param giveaway giveaway data to save
     * @param photo photo of the giveaway item
     * @param principal authenticated user
     * @return status code and errors
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addGiveaway(@RequestParam("giveaway") Giveaway giveaway, 
                                              @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo,
                                              @PathVariable("campaignId") long campaignId,
                                              Principal principal) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Made it into the controller");

        Campaign campaign = campaignService.findOne(campaignId);
        campaignService.verifyCampaignOwnership(
                            businessUserService
                                .findByEmail(principal.getName()), campaign);

        //Validate form input
        HttpHeaders headers = giveawayService.validateGiveawayData(giveaway);

        //Validate image size & file type
        String extension = FileUtils.resolveExtension(photo.getContentType());
        if(FileUtils.isImage(extension)) {
            if(FileUtils.checkDimensions(photo, GiveawayService.MIN_ALLOWED_SIZE, 
                                         GiveawayService.MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE, GiveawayService.MIN_ALLOWED_SIZE, 
                                         GiveawayService.MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE, true)) {
                headers.add("Error-Giveaway-Image-Size", "Giveaway photo must be square and between 64-612 pixels.");
            }
        } else {
            headers.add("Error-Giveaway-Image-Type", "Only .jpg and .png file types are allowed.");
        }

        //If headers are not empty, then there's either validation or input errors 
        if(!headers.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            giveaway.setPhotoExtension(extension);
            giveaway.setStatus(GiveawayStatus.INACTIVE);
            giveaway = giveawayService.save(giveaway);

            FileUtils.uploadResource(photo, giveaway.getGiveawayId() + extension, GiveawayService.GIVEAWAY_STORING_LOCATION);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the giveaway POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GIVEAWAYS")
public class Giveaway implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8835490774774467020L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="giveaway_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long giveawayId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="give_campaign_id"), nullable=false)
    private Campaign campaign;

    @Column(name="giveaway_item")
    private String giveawayItem;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="photo_extension")
    private String photoExtension;

    @Column(name="amount_of_items")
    private int amountOfItems;

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name="eligibility")
    private String eligibility;

   //Getters and setters below...
```

And here's the JSON created from the form sent to the back end:

`{giveawayItem: "testing", description: "test123", amountOfItems: 4, eligibility: "Followers"}`

**EDIT 3**
Whenever I use `angular.toJson` or `JSON.stringify` on the data above, it turns it into this:

`{"description":"dfgdg","amountOfItems":5,"eligibility":"Followers"}`

For some reason, `giveawayItem` disappears. I don't know if that's causing any issues, but it's certainly troubling.

**EDIT 4**

Debug logging

```
2016-10-31 13:40:35.097 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/dashboard/campaigns/1/giveaways]
2016-10-31 13:40:35.098 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /dashboard/campaigns/1/giveaways
2016-10-31 13:40:35.102 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.glimpsmedia.app.controllers.GiveawayController.addGiveaway(com.glimpsmedia.app.model.Giveaway,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,long,java.security.Principal) throws java.lang.Exception]
2016-10-31 13:40:35.121 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
2016-10-31 13:40:35.139 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Error resolving argument [0] [type=com.glimpsmedia.app.model.Giveaway]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.glimpsmedia.app.controllers.GiveawayController]
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.glimpsmedia.app.controllers.GiveawayController.addGiveaway(com.glimpsmedia.app.model.Giveaway,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,long,java.security.Principal) throws java.lang.Exception]


org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Giveaway parameter 'giveaway' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:195) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:104) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.glimpsmedia.app.security.StatelessAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(StatelessAuthenticationFilter.java:52) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.glimpsmedia.app.security.CsrfTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfTokenFilter.java:46) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]

2016-10-31 13:40:35.140 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.glimpsmedia.app.controllers.GiveawayController.addGiveaway(com.glimpsmedia.app.model.Giveaway,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,long,java.security.Principal) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Giveaway parameter 'giveaway' is not present
2016-10-31 13:40:35.140 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.glimpsmedia.app.controllers.GiveawayController.addGiveaway(com.glimpsmedia.app.model.Giveaway,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,long,java.security.Principal) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Giveaway parameter 'giveaway' is not present
2016-10-31 13:40:35.140 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.glimpsmedia.app.controllers.GiveawayController.addGiveaway(com.glimpsmedia.app.model.Giveaway,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,long,java.security.Principal) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Giveaway parameter 'giveaway' is not present
2016-10-31 13:40:35.141 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-10-31 13:40:35.141 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-10-31 13:40:35.142 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/error]
2016-10-31 13:40:35.142 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-10-31 13:40:35.144 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2016-10-31 13:40:35.144 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
2016-10-31 13:40:35.149 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Mon Oct 31 13:40:35 EDT 2016, status=400, error=Bad Request, exception=org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException, message=Required Giveaway parameter 'giveaway' is not present, path=/dashboard/campaigns/1/giveaways}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@7cbe3a05]
2016-10-31 13:40:35.149 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-10-31 13:40:35.149 DEBUG 2716 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Can you try enabling debug level logging on the core spring classes?  Like  `<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />`?  Also, not an expert on JSON, but that string fails on http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @bphilipnyc I'm using Spring Boot, so I don't have any XML configuration files. I'll look up how to enable it in my application.properties file. In the mean time, could you look at my edit #3?

Comment: In your application.properties, set `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`

Comment: Off the top of my head, it seems odd to be using form-multipart for PUT. I'd tend to use JSON instead.

Comment: @chrylis The reason I'm using multipart is because I'm sending a file alongside form data. The photo parameter is an image.

Comment: Not sure whether this will help, but you can try setting it to undefined instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039852/send-formdata-with-other-field-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

Your request url **/dashboard/campaigns/"+campaignId+"/giveaways** is not actually mapped to the `controller` method.

As you need to pass `campaignId` as `@PathVariable`, you should map it, in your controller method.

Class Level Mapping (at top): `/dashboard/campaigns/`

Method Level Mapping : `{campaignId}/giveaways`

The code follows below:

```
    @RestController(value = "/dashboard/campaigns/") {
    public class GiveawayController {
           @RequestMapping(value="{campaignId}/giveaways", method =RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addGiveaway(    
             @RequestParam("giveaway")Giveaway giveaway, 
             @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo,
             @PathVariable("campaignId") long campaignId,
              Principal principal) throws Exception {
             //code here
        }
    }
```

P.S.: I have assumed that `/dashboard/campaigns/` mapping at class level.

Comment: Still have the same issue unfortunately. I even tried removing the `{campaignId}` field entirely, manually entering the number "1" when I needed that variable. I'm still getting a 400 response.

Comment: yeah, one second.

Comment: It shouldn't matter because the logger at the top of the controller is not printing anything. That means it's an error at the request level right?

Comment: Did you look at my answer closely how I configured class level and method level mappings ?

Comment: yes, I did it exactly how you had it. I reverted it back when it didn't do anything. I even tried copying the whole mapping above the controller method itself.

Comment: I added the Giveaway POJO and the JSON sent to the back end.

Comment: In angularjs change it to 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127058/discussion-between-javaguy-and-jake-miller).

Comment: This isn't true. I fixed it with my current mapping set up and it's working 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of your problem.

Actually you're struggling to transmit the object from the *Angular* front side and trying to get it through *@RequestParam* which is naturally can't be straightforward as *@RequestParam* will normally works on string type, means it can't just map a complex object . It's all makes sense as the *400 http* code is indicating a malformed request.

A possible solution (notice that *`@RequestBody`* instead of *`@RequestParam`* on *Giveaway* ):

```
// Angular side
$scope.addGiveaway = function(campaignId){
        var photo = $scope.photo;
        var giveaway = $scope.giveaway;
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('photo', photo);
        data.append('giveaway', giveaway);
        var uploadUrl = "/dashboard/campaigns/"+campaignId+"/giveaways";
        $http.put(uploadUrl, data, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        });


// Spring side
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addGiveaway(@RequestBody Giveaway giveaway, 
                                              @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo,
                                              @PathVariable("campaignId") long campaignId,
                                              Principal principal) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Causes a 415 response. Here's the error: `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBQQTVmmDn1riaVzC;charset=UTF-8' not supported`. I think the boundary is the issue but I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: My mistake, the JSON part is just fine (as it was being sent), and the content type of the HTTP header must be *multipart/form-data*, but I'm not sure whether or not this *@RequestBody* needs a json provider to be set up for.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I changed the `Giveaway` object to a String and parsed that with an `ObjectMapper`. Here's my new controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addGiveaway(@RequestParam("giveaway") String giveawayData, 
                                              @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo,
                                              @PathVariable("campaignId") long campaignId,
                                              Principal principal) throws Exception {
```

I then used `var giveaway = angular.toJson($scope.giveaway)` to format the json properly. I then appended the giveaway data to the end of the request instead of adding it to the form data, like this:

`'.../giveaways?giveaway=' + giveaway;`