# I am trying to upload a file to Django server using angularjs 1.6.5. I am not able to upload file using $http.patch method

Tags: angularjs, django

Using Angularjs 1.6.5 I am trying to upload a file to the Django server. When I try to upload the file I am not sure what type of 'Content-Type' header should be passed with the $http.patch method. Here is the following my Angular apps config:-

```
var app = angular.module("edit_modules", []);

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
});
```

And this is my patch method:-

```
$http.patch(url, data, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
function successCallback(response){
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(response);
};
function errorCallback(error){
    alert("Error Uploading!");
    console.log(error);
};
```

When I pass `{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }` through the Header I get the following error:-

```
"The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
Status :- 400
```

Since its content-type is file I used the following header  `{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8'}` . But then I got this error:-

```
Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None
Status :- 400
```

As suggested in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722093/send-multipart-form-data-files-with-angular-using-http) I tried the following header as well `{'Content-Type': undefined}` But this as well did not resolve my problem and I got the following error:-

```
Unsupported media type "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" in request. 
Status :- 415
```

However when I tried with simple text fields the PATCH method worked with the header supplied being {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }. I am not sure where the problem is. I even tried to see the console for what data was being set to be patched

```
data = {
    "video": element.files[0]
};
console.log(data);
```

THIS is what i got on console:-

```
{video: File(99861)}video: File(99861) {name: "Capture2.PNG", lastModified: 1517491665223, lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 01 2018 18:57:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 99861, …}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Label is just a video but it can be any type of file.

Comment: Thats not what I am not looking for.

Comment: But thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039852/send-formdata-with-other-field-in-angular) I found that you need to attach the File Object to be sent using FormData. Also you need an additional header in config `transformRequest: angular.identity,`. Here is the successful PATCH method that worked for me.

```
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('video', element.files[0]);
        $http.patch(url, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        function successCallback(response){
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(response);
        };
        function errorCallback(error){
            alert("Error Uploading!");
            console.log(error);
        };
```

In the second line `'video'` is the REST API Endpoint's variable where my file will be stored. In order to avoid the error

```
Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None
```

I have left the `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}`.