# post image and other info without using formdata in nativescript(typescript + angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

i tired this one 
[Send FormData with other field in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039852/send-formdata-with-other-field-in-angular) 
not work out for me.

i need to access the image from file system then send it.

```
        let fullPath = path.join(folder.path, "1.png");
        const imageFromLocalFile: ImageSource = <ImageSource> fromFile(fullPath);
        const base64String = imageFromLocalFile.toBase64String("png");
```

Answer (score 0):

FormData is not supported by NativeScript. You have 2 options,

1. Send the image as Base64 string, looks like you already know how to get the Base64 string form image, you may just send it as a param in JOSN body.
2. Use [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/) plugin that can directly upload the file.